# Is it possible to use existing Appium session for Python client?

Tags: python, appium

I would like to use existing Appium session in python code. I use python **Appium-Python-Client** library

According to https://appiumpro.com/editions/78 post, that is possible for java client (code bellow)

```
   String sessionId = "d8080676-634d-49fc-8624-fc7b57c5d530";
   AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub" , sessionId);
```

I didn't have success with my tries in python (code bellow)

```
   driver = webdriver.Remote(Config.APPIUM_URL)
   driver.session_id = appium_session.log_info
```

> Err is  Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. Original error: You must include a
>   platformName capability

```
   driver = webdriver.Remote(Config.APPIUM_URL, desired_capabilities={})
   driver.session_id = appium_session.log_info
```

> Err is selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown
>   server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
>   error: You must include a platformName

It seems there is no such functionality for python client for current time. (2020-04)

Answer (score 0):

This link helps you to get the current session and reusing of it in Selenium. You can find something similar to this in Appium also, because it uses the same library.

https://tarunlalwani.com/post/reusing-existing-browser-session-selenium/